# Understanding what sort of objects can be dictionary keys

Tags: python, module, immutability

I'm in the middle of a discussion with a fellow SO user in which we're trying to determine whether a Python module, when held in a variable -- e.g., `sys`, following `import sys` -- is mutable or immutable.

Does anyone have a good answer?

The question arose from a discussion of what sort of objects can be keys for Python `dicts`.  The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html) claim that "only immutable elements can be used as dictionary keys, and hence only tuples and not lists can be used as keys."  But a module -- as just one example of a mutable object -- can be used as a key, as in

```
x = {sys: 1}
```

Comment: How could it be anything other than mutable? Is `import foo; foo.bar = 'baz'` not enough to demonstrate that?

Comment: Why don't you just try changing one and see?

Comment: yeah.  i guess i was wondering about the distinction between `sys` itself and its methods and constants.  but i see now that `sys` is of course nothing but its methods and constants.  i think i'll delete this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Python docs claim that "only immutable elements can be used as
>   dictionary keys, and hence only tuples and not lists can be used as
>   keys." But a module -- as just one example of a mutable object -- can
>   be used as a key

It's not quite true that things have to be immutable to be used as dict keys. Rather, everything about them that gets considered for `==` comparisons has to be immutable. `==` for modules works by object identity, so doing something like

```
import sys
sys.foo = 3
```

doesn't change any information used for `==` comparisons. Thus, they can be used as dict keys.

Comment: hold on.  what if you did `sys.__eq__ = lambda self, other: . . .`

Comment: @dbliss: Wouldn't do anything to `==`. Special method lookup for operators and `hash` and things like that bypasses the object's dict.

Comment: sorry, i'm trying to work out what you mean by "the object's dict."

Comment: OK, i think i follow you.  defining `sys.__eq__` for the *instance* `sys` puts an entry in the instance's dict (i.e., `__dict__`), but does not define `__eq__` for the module *class*.  is that right?

Comment: Right; if you could modify `type(sys).__eq__`, you might break the hashability of the `module` instance that `sys` refers to. However, you cannot set attributes of the built-in `module` type.

Answer (score 3):

It is mutable.  You can do things like this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.blah = 100
>>> sys.blah
100
```